# Laravel foreign key relation - Unknown column in field list

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have Member and SkyMedRep models:

```
class SkyMedRep extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','rep_id',
    ];

    public function members()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Member');
    }
}

class Member extends User
{
    public function sky_med_rep()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SkyMedRep');
    }
}
```

This is migration for Member:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('sky_med_rep_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('members', function($table) {
       $table->foreign('sky_med_rep_id')->references('id')-   >on('sky_med_reps')->nullable(true);
    });
}
```

Member model contains foreign key referencing SkyMedRep model.After defining such relationship, I am trying to assign object of SkyMedRep model to the object of Member model like:

```
$member->sky_med_rep = $sky_med_rep;
```

Here, $member is the object of Member model and $sky_med_rep is the object of SkyMedRep model.

When I try $member->save(), I am getting error "Unknown column 'sky_med_rep' in field list". It seems that sky_med_rep is not being able to treat as foreign key reference. Below is my code to save the data:

```
    $member = new Member();
    $member->sky_med_member_number = $request->input("sky_med_member")['member_number'];
    $sky_med_rep = SkyMedRep::firstOrNew(['rep_id' => $request->input("sky_med_member")['rep_id']]);
    $sky_med_rep->name = $request->input("sky_med_member")['name'];
    $sky_med_rep->save();
    $member->sky_med_rep = $sky_med_rep;
    $member->save();
```

Comment: can you tell me when exactly you get the error? also tell me your query ?

Comment: $member = new Member();

$member->sky_med_member_number = $request->input("sky_med_member")['member_number'];

$sky_med_rep = SkyMedRep::firstOrNew(['rep_id' => $request->input("sky_med_member")['rep_id']]);

$sky_med_rep->name = $request->input("sky_med_member")['name'];
$sky_med_rep->save();
$member->sky_med_rep = $sky_med_rep;
$member->save();

I am getting the error while saving member object. I have assigned $member->sky_med_rep by SkyMedRep object. But while saving, I am getting the error unknown field list

Comment: can you post your queries, that how fetching and how you assigning, add your details in question

Comment: Quazi, last few lines of my question consist of the code which saves member object's data into database.

Comment: do you have this column `sky_med_member_number` in your DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$member->sky_med_rep = $sky_med_rep;` You should write `$member->sky_med_rep->associate($sky_med_rep);`.

Also have a look at http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ coding style guide. Method names should be camelCase, not underscore.

Comment: Great. I just migrated from django to laravel. I am new here. But Thanks it worked like a charm (y)